# Unable to figure out how to move a file to a folder after they have been matched based on an ID that they both have in their names Google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In Google Drive I am trying to compare an id in a file name against folders named with that id, and if they match, to move that file to that folder.

Some of the problems that the program has to account for are:

1. Since the id is generated from the customer's name it does not have a set length
2. The id could be anywhere in the file name, not just at the beginning or end
3. There can be multiple files with different names containing the same id, so the program
   has to loop

Things that make this easier:

1. All of the folders are in the same parent folder and have the id as their name, so the
   program can use the list of folder names as a list of the ids
2. The files are all in the same parent folder, and there will be no other files in the
   folder, so the loop can just run until the folder is empty

So far I have written a code that successfully:

1. Accesses both parent folders by id
2. Loops through the file folder until it has checked all files, and pushes the file names to
   an array called "fileNames"
3. Loops through the folders and compares the current folder's name to the file names for a
   match, and pushes the folder names to an array called "childNames"

I have created two files in the "files" folder to test with, "john1111_test.pdf" and "thomas2222_test.pdf", and two folders in the "childName" folder "john1111" and "thomas2222"

The part that I am stuck on is copying the file to the folder it matched with.

```js
var childFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('****').getFolders(); // Folder containing folders
var files = DriveApp.getFolderById('****').getFiles(); // Folder containing the files

  var fileNames = [];
   while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file1 = files.next();
     var fName = file1.getName()

     Logger.log(fName);

     fileNames.push(fName);
     
   }

  var childNames = [];
   while (childFolder.hasNext()) {
     var child = childFolder.next();
     var cdName = child.getName();

     Logger.log(cdName);
     
     childNames.push(cdName);
     
     const match = fileNames.find(element => {
       if (element.includes(cdName)) {

// This is the area that I am having issues with         
         let folderMatch = childFolder.getFoldersByName(cdName);
         let fileMatch = files.getFilesByName(element);
         folderMatch.addFile(fileMatch)


         return true;
        }
     });
     console.log(match);
   }
```

I receive an error saying that foldermatch.addFile is not a function. I have tried cdName.addFile(element) as well.

Comment: outputFolder and startFolder are undefined

Comment: please setup a simple example with example folders and example files in a file tree and show how you wish the program to move the.  If you having trouble moving them the drive Drive API v2 `Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": folder.getId()}]}, file.getId());` you will need the file id and the folder id.  Please show examples of how the different type of file names and where the your id's are found.

Comment: @Cooper I'm not sure how to add a file tree here, but I explained the file structure in the post when I said "I have created two files in the "files" folder to test with, "john1111_test.pdf" and "thomas2222_test.pdf", and two folders in the "childName" folder "john1111" and "thomas2222"". But incase that wasn't clear enough, there are two folder in the root of my drive  , files and the parent folder containing the folders I mentioned earlier, john111, and thomas2222. those are also the id's that will appear in the file names. The files are in the files folder and are john111_test.pdf and

Comment: @Lord_Kaname previous continued- thomas2222_test.pdf. john111_test.pdf needs to be moved to the john1111 folder and thomas2222_test.pdf needs to be moved to the thomas2222 folder. One of the issues is that the file name could be test_thomas2222_1.pdf and that also needs to be found and moved to the thomas2222 folder

Comment: What are the rules for creating the folder names from the file names

Comment: Do you have somewhere, like a Google Sheet, where these IDs are stored? The problem would become much easier to solve. The way you put it, you would have to use regular expressions or other string manipulation to extract the id if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Moving Files

```
function movingFile() {
  const files = DriveApp.getFolderById('1jeAihkCiA--EfAl150IXrXDUa-MhYSKY');
  const folders = DriveApp.getFolderById('1xB4XTG8d1DYtthVQQqkSQCqvzv-TGWtW');
  const fldrs = folders.getFolders();
  let fldrNames = [];
  let fldrA = [];
  while (fldrs.hasNext()) {
    let fldr = fldrs.next()
    fldrNames.push(fldr.getName());
    fldrA.push(fldr);
  }
  const fs = files.getFiles();
  while (fs.hasNext()) {
    let file = fs.next();
    let idx = fldrNames.indexOf(file.getName().slice(0,file.getName().indexOf('_')));
    if(~fldrNames.indexOf(file.getName().slice(0,file.getName().indexOf('_')))) {//if folder  is present move it here
     //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(file.getName().slice(0,file.getName().indexOf('_')));
      Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": fldrA[idx].getId()}]}, file.getId());
    } else {//if it is not then create it first and xfer
      let f = folders.createFolder(file.getName().slice(0,file.getName().indexOf('_')));
      fldrA.push(f);
      Drive.Files.update({"parents": [{"id": f.getId()}]}, file.getId());
      fldrNames.push(file.getName().slice(0,file.getName().indexOf('_')));//added folder name to fldrNames so that it will be used again if there are more files with that name
      
    }
  }
}
```

Before:

[image]

[image]

After:

[image]

[image]

Need to enable Drive API Version 2

Comment: I'm running into an issue when I try this code with multiple files with the same ID, such as if I have thomas2222_test1.pdf  and thomas2222_test2.pdf, where it creates a new folder for each file with that ID if the currently existing folder/folders already have a file in them.  If I comment out the line that creates new folders if none are found it won't do anything if the ID on the files matches a folder with a file already in it. Would you mind helping me with this?

Comment: If you had answered my question about rules for creating folders and how they relate to file names, I could potentially solve this problem.  We are not inside of your mind we do not know all of the allowable variations.  I am only using the string that comes before the underscore in the file name.  So please provide us more information about how the folder names correlate to the file names.

Comment: I’m sorry that this isn’t making much sense, but I am very grateful for the help. The folder names will be the same as the first part of the file name, which will be the last name plus 4 digits. There will be one folder already generated for each ID by a separate system. That folder needs to have all files starting with that ID moved into it. Unfortunately, there can’t be a set number of characters for the last name. So, if it would be easier, could it take the name of each folder and search for file names containing that rather than trying to separate the id out and search for files?

Comment: Okay try it again.  I forgot to add the new folderName to the array of foldernames

Comment: It is still creating a second folder when one already exists. It adds the first thomas2222 file to the preexisting folder but then creates a new folder for the second and third thomas2222 file

Comment: I'll have to set up my test bed again and see what the issue is.

Comment: I think this will do it for you